# Using PHP and SQL, what is the best way to store association from multiple rows of one table to a single row of another for dynamic webpages

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Say I have a list of clients with their client IDs and other information and I want to add multiple clients to one batch/order. The order table would dynamically propagate on the webpage with small order summary tickets for each order, and then when clicked on show more info about the order including all the client IDs and other information associated with it.
The functionality will include adding and removing the users from the specific orders, and obviously storing them to be recalled again

I'm new to PHP and SQL, I can propagate the client table and order tickets well dynamically, but Google has only taken me this far.

The best solution I came up with is to store a list of the users ids in a new row of the order table and write PHP script to edit it. Is this possible? Or even a good way of going about it? Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: It is possible but a bad idea. Use (native) database relations design. `orders`, `order_items`, `clients`. Search on Google for type of relations like "OneToMany", "ManyToMany". Depending on the relation, you'd need another table. Or the `order_item` table needs a column `client_id`.

Comment: `he best solution I came up with is to store a list of the users ids in a new row of the order table and write PHP script to edit it. Is this possible` ...yes but it's usually a bad idea. It sounds like a many-to-many relationship between clients and orders probably. So you'd have a Clients table, an Orders table, and a ClientOrders table where each row contains one unique combination of Client ID and Order ID. Then you can use JOIN queries to fetch all the related clients for any given order, or vice-versa.

Comment: As an aside, please take some time out now to study relational database design before you go any further with this project and get yourself into a big knotty mess. Always get the foundations in place before you try to build the building.

Comment: P.S. In your question you switch terminology repeatedly between clients / users, and orders / tickets / batches. I _think_ there are really only two entities in play here (clients and orders) but the mish-mash of unexplained terminology makes it less than clear. If you're writing a specification and desgining a database, it needs to be 100% crystal clear, consistent and unambiguous as to what everything means and how they are related otherwise - again - you'll tie yourself, and anyone else you're working on this task, in unpleasant and confusing knots.